How to make type inference work on a piece of code from constructor to generic value type?
There are definitely things I don't understand in the way the type system is working.
For this piece of code,
export abstract class EcsResourceFactory<TResult> {
  protected abstract build(): TResult
}

class ResourceContainer  {
  public resolve<
  TResult,
  TFactory extends EcsResourceFactory<TResult>,
>(type: new () => TFactory): TResult
  // Other overloads here

  public resolve(key: any): any {
     // implementation here
  }
}

class MyResource extends EcsResourceFactory<{ foo: string }> {
  protected build() {
    return { foo: 'bar' }
  }
}


const result = new ResourceContainer().resolve(MyResource)
console.log(result.foo)

The type of result is unknown

I can't figure out a way of how it can be infered to {foo: string} ?
I have tried for instance this:
 public resolve<
    TResult,
    TFactory extends EcsResourceFactory<TResult>,
    TResource extends new (world: EcsWorld) => TFactory,
  >(type: TResource): TResult

But same result
NB: example here is widely simplified, in usage contexte, ResourceFactory class has for instance constructor parameters.

Constraints are not used as inference sites; therefore your TResult type param in resolve has nowhere from which to infer anything (and your second attempt makes this even worse by putting even more uninferrable types in the way). Given this example you should refactor to the version shown in this playground link where there is only TResult involved. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer or find a suitable duplication source; if not, what am I missing?

oh wow, it just worked. . I actually overcomplicated the genericity.... I'll add your answer in a response post. Thank you very much

I'd prefer to write my own answer, if you don't mind.

Oh ok, no problem. I have deleted mine. I'll accept it as ansyer as soon as I'll see it

TypeScript does not infer type parameters from generic constraints. So in
public resolve<TResult, TFactory extends EcsResourceFactory<TResult>>(
    type: new () => TFactory
): TResult

there is nowhere from which TResult can be inferred. You were presumably hoping that TFactory could be inferred from type and then TResult could be inferred from the constraint on TFactory, but that doesn't happen. So you get TFactory inferred properly, but then TResult fails to infer (and falls back to unknown).
There was an old feature request at microsoft/TypeScript#7234 asking for constraints to be used as inference sites, but it was declined in favor of having people rewrite their call signatures.

Generally speaking you should use as few generic type parameters as possible, so in the case of your example code I'd remove TFactory entirely and just use TResult directly.
public resolve<TResult>(type: new () => EcsResourceFactory<TResult>): TResult

That behaves how you want:
const result = new ResourceContainer().resolve(MyResource)
// const result: { foo: string; }

If for some reason you need both type parameters, then you can take the suggestion from microsoft/TypeScript#7234 and use an intersection to put both type parameters in the same inferrable spot:
public resolve<TResult, TFactory extends EcsResourceFactory<TResult>>(
    type: new () => (TFactory & EcsResourceFactory<TResult>)
): TResult

That will still work, but now TFactory is available.
Playground link to code
